# File upload by ajax with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, django, ajax

I would like to make file uploader on a web page by PHP and javascript.
However, I could not run PHP and save a file on the server. So I would like you to help me.

How can I save the uploaded file on my Linux system?

My system is Linux (Ubuntu MATE) - Apache - Django.
The code is following.

## file_upload.html

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h3>File Upload</h3>
        <form id="my_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="file_1">
            <button type="button" onclick="file_upload()">upload</button>
        </form>
    </center>

<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/file_upload.js" %}></script>
</body>
```

## file_upload.js

```
function file_upload()
{
    var formdata = new FormData($('#my_form').get(0));
    $.ajax({
        url  : "/upload.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : formdata,
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        dataType    : "html"
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("fail");
    });
}
```

## upload.php

```
<?php
$file_tmp  = $_FILES["file_1"]["tmp_name"];
console.log($file_tmp)

$file_save = "./" . $_FILES["file_1"]["name"];

$result = @move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_save);
if ( $result === true ) {
    echo "UPLOAD OK";
} else {
    echo "UPLOAD NG";
}
```

When I run these code, the response is only showing the form data (content of PHP) and PHP is not run. I think I can save a file at $file_save on Linux, but I cannot do.

Please tell me the way to make it.

Thank you in advance.
I am looking forward to your reply!

Comment: Why is there an `@` symbol in your php code? Remove that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I removed @ from move_uploaded_file, but the result is the same.

Comment: `console.log` won't work in php, remove that as well.

Comment: I forgot to remove it. Sorry. But the result is not changed.

Comment: I can't find any more syntax errors. In other cases php is executed on your server?

Comment: Maybe yes. A django server is launched on apache and display an html in templates directory, and php is located in the same directory.

Comment: The directory shouldn't matter, create a simple `<?php echo "Hello, World!";` and see if it executes. If not you will have to configure your apache to run `*.php` files as PHP.

Comment: I changed php as follows: <?php phpinfo();
But the php is automatically commented out.
I am now checking the apache config.

Comment: I checked apache setting and phpinfo() worked properly.
However when I launch a server with django, php does not work.
Do you have any idea to work php on django server?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413910/6239524

Comment: Thank you. PHP works at a port different from django.
(I use 8000 port for django, and 80 port for php.)