# How to translate attached something.inc(php included file) to python?

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I got an file which is php included. It needs to be translate to python and how to handle post request on it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an HTTP server alongside django to host that php file. Maybe this may be of help:

[Running PHP in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410904/running-php-in-django)